# how can we run php5.6 and php7.0 on same Ubuntu machine?

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, php-7

I have configured my system with `Ubuntu-16.04`, [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/fr/download.html#download-linux) 5.6, now as a `php` web developer I need to change my `php` version to test my code works on `php7.0`, so I did some googling but not found perfect solution. I am not sure but in `Ubuntu` you can multiple profiles and you can actually switch profile to run different environment. so, is it possible to create profile and run standalone `xampp` or something kind of this to run both `php5.6` and `php7.0` for same time with `xampp`.

Comment: I never understood why people use something like `xampp` on a Linux system instead of simply installing the well prepared packages for the components apache http server, mysql RDBMS and php with three mouse clicks.

Comment: Since services like http server and mysql server are system services, so not directly connected to a system user, it is not that easy to make the chosen php version depend on the user profile. You can however certainly install multiple versions in parallel. No issue for command line versions, you just pick the correct one you want to use. For the intepration into the http server however you have to configure different setups: you can integrate one as apache module and use the other php version as cgi or fastcgi execution helper. That works.

Comment: Another wide spread approach for such situations is to simply use separate virtual environments, so virtual machines or, even better, docker containers, that share some part of the systems file system where the actual scripts are located.

Comment: @arkascha no reason to use specifically `xampp`, but there's a reason to use something like container or VM (for ex. Docker or Vagrant) - you have no reason either to have your `php`, `mysql`, etc. running all the time, and running and shutting them down isn't a comfortable thing as well. So using VM or container makes sense - you just run or halt it whenever you need.

Comment: @BogdanLapchenkov I don't see much difference in starting / stopping a container or a service. I see that as a question of personal preferences.

Comment: @arkascha yep, totally agreed.

Comment: @arkascha thanks for your support, can't we just create new profile and use enviroment variable according to php version, so we don't need to change exsisting projects setup with XAMPP.

Comment: I have the impression you did not consider what I wrote in my second comment above. Or is `xampp` able to support two separate php versions? If so, then what is your question here? Once more: you need to differ between a system service and user stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing phpbrew. It's a program for managing php versions I'm working with for some time already.

Here's the link : [phpbrew/phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew)

You can find instructions upon installation and usage at their [official page](http://phpbrew.github.io/phpbrew/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply run as many versions of php as you like, try installing vagrant box. Add multiple boxes for different php versions.

Comment: Though not really required to operate different php versions you _can_ do that by using virtual machines. When recommending that as an answer you should however also sketch out the basic approach instead of just dropping the term here...

Comment: I know I can use vgrant but from long time I have used xampp and lot of projects needs to migration if I use vgrant now.